# Possible to display date and time of emails in Outlook 365 web app inbox and sent-items and custom folders for items older than "this week"?

Tags: outlook-web-access

For emails older than "this week", is it possible to display the time as well as the date on all Outlook web app email lists: InBox, Sent, and custom folders?

Outlook displays time-only (09:01) for today's emails, the day-name and time for "this week", the day-name and short-date (Fri 10/15) for emails older than this week within the last 30 days, and just the date (e.g. 9/18/2021) on mail older than 30 days.

I would gladly dispense with the day-name to get the time-of-day for emails within the last 30 days. In my particular case, **09/21 16:22** would be so much more helpful than **Tue 09/21**, especially on custom folders where rules have directed many  event-logging emails, all nearly identical, and I have a need to review emails from a particular time-range on a particular day.